# Adding SDL2 extension libraries to android project

Tags: android, windows, android-ndk, sdl-2, sdl-image

Hi i just setup SDL2 for android on windows 7 with this guide - http://www.mosaicit.de/android-sdl-c-build-system-compiling.
But the problem is that i would like to use SDL2_image and ttf but i don't know how to add them to this kind of project and i couldn't find anything on the subject elsewhere.

```
    Compile error:
    fatal error: SDL_image.h: No such file or

    Main.cpp
    #include <SDL_image.h>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to download and build SDL_image just like you did with SDL:
https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_image/

Here's a specific tutorial for SDL_image and Android:
http://jorhlok.net/2013/07/31/from-nix-to-android-with-sdl2-and-sdl_image-using-the-command-line-of-course/

Comment: It has rained a bit since then but have we a way to compile sdl_image extension using the command line? The provided link is broken.

Comment: To me the issue right now is that gradle is complaining about SDL2 dependency.

Comment: @Iñigo probably you should open a new issue with your specific error and reference this one.